# wordpress update_core.php, themes.php and plugins.php error

Tags: php, wordpress

Initially i thought it might be a plugin conflict, so i renamed the plugins directory to plugins-temp and created a new empty directory "plugins" to reinstall them one by one to see which one caused the problem. However, the error still occurred even with an empty plugins directory. After that I thought that it might be a theme issue, so i tried to change the theme from wp-admin, and i noticed that that page also returns an error so I changed the custom theme to "twentysixteen" in the database. However, the themes page still returns an error and the plugins page wasn't working either. Poking around the wp-admin page i also found that the updates page on the dashboard was returning an error. I assume it is a database conflict but i cannot reset the entire database. What values could i reset in the database that would reset the settings on those pages? In addition, I also updated to the latest version of wordpress(4.8.2).

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: is there any error message that you can share with us? Hard to know which setting to change or if it's actually the thing you have to do to solve your problem. I'd personnally go from a fresh install with a save of the database to be sure that the db is the guilty one; but i'm a cautious guy in a way

Answer (score 1):

In your situation it is very hard to pinpoint what's wrong with your website but you can try narrow down the source of the error.

**Possible causes:**

There might be a corrupted file somewhere in your WordPress core or broken theme or badly coded plugin that mess up your database.

**Backup first:**

Nevertheless try backing up all your WordPress files including the database before doing anything else.

**Reinstall:**

Once you have your backup delete whatever files you have and reinstall your site bit by bit to troubleshoot the issue. This will also ensure you have a clean WordPress core files.

1. Install a fresh copy of WordPress with default theme and database installed.
2. Once done upload your theme and activate it and make sure the site is showing up just fine.
3. Followed by upload folders and plugins. Reactivate the plugins and check the site again.
4. Lastly replace your database file and check the site, if there is no error that means the error should be somewhere in your core or the templates. If there are errors then the errors most likely originated from your database.